# How do you go from Palomino to Venezuela?

Tags: colombia, land-borders, venezuela

How can I get to Venezuela from Palomino Colombia? Time is not really an issue but I would like to know the safest/easiest way to cross this border if anyone has recently done it.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to go ? Are you just looking to cross the border ?

Comment: Safest and easiest may not be at all the same thing. The safest way is probably to fly, for instance, which is probably not the cheapest, nor the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Go Northeast, to Maicao, there is a Colombian-Venezuelan border. You should note that is very probable that border is [closed](http://www.eltiempo.com/colombia/otras-ciudades/crisis-en-frontera-con-venezuela-por-paraguachon-no-dejan-pasar-ni-a-los-venezolanos/16363816), due to Venezuelan government decision.

Other way to go to Venezuela: Go to Cartagena, there is a flight from Cartagena to Maracaibo